# Is there a substitute for ejecting a SD card on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, bash

I am having issues ejecting an SD card from an ubuntu Rpi in my bash script. When I run the command to eject, the following error is displayed

```
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT       
loop0         7:0    0 48.9M  1 loop /snap/core18/1949
loop1         7:1    0 48.9M  1 loop /snap/core18/2073
loop2         7:2    0 59.6M  1 loop /snap/lxd/20330  
loop3         7:3    0 28.1M  1 loop /snap/snapd/12397
loop4         7:4    0   27M  1 loop /snap/snapd/10709
loop5         7:5    0 61.6M  1 loop /snap/lxd/19040  
sda           8:0    1 29.8G  0 disk
├─sda1        8:1    1  256M  0 part
└─sda2        8:2    1  7.2G  0 part
mmcblk0     179:0    0 29.8G  0 disk
├─mmcblk0p1 179:1    0  256M  0 part
└─mmcblk0p2 179:2    0 29.6G  0 part /
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ eject sda
eject: tried to use `/dev/sda' as device name but it is no block device
not an sg device, or old sg driver
eject: unable to eject, last error: Inappropriate ioctl for device
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ eject /dev/sda
eject: tried to use `/dev/sda' as device name but it is no block device
eject: unable to find or open device for: `/dev/sda'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, `eject` is for CD players - players that have the mechanical components to physically eject a CD. A CD is a round, shiny disk that spins around in the drive. Your SD card is a fundamentally different type of storage media, and AFAIK has no mechanical components capable of ejecting it.